# iOS double load audio before it will play

Tags: ios, ipad, audio, load, jwplayer

I have a link that loads a song into the player and then when you click on the player, the song starts. This is fine on PC/Mac but iOS is needing the song to be loaded twice before it starts playing. So what I am having to do is the following:

I've been testing this in an iPad 2.

1. Click the link to load the song
2. Click the player to start the song - I get the spinning "buffering" progress wheel but no song plays
3. Click the link to load the song a 2nd time
4. Song begins to play

I know that iOS will not autoplay a song, but why should I need to load the song twice before the song will play. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
// Set up JWPlayer
jwplayer('track_player').setup({
flashplayer: "player.swf",
height: 200,
width: 400,
controlbar: 'bottom',
events: {
onReady: function(event) {
player = jwplayer('track_player');
}
}
});
});

var player = null; // JWPlayer reference

function loadFile() {
player.load({
'file':'http://www.mydomain.com/songs/song.mp3'
});
}
// ]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="loadFile()">Load File</a><br /><br />
<div id="track_player"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to see the problem live.

http://www.tonedeafdesign.com/ios-audio-test.php

I'm sure I'm missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED - Here's what changed. I added to the config:

```
autostart: false
```

and then chained a .play() to the end of the .load(...) in the loadFile() function, so it would look like this:

```
player.load({'file':'http://www.mydomain.com/songs/song.mp3').play();
```